# RegEx to match text and enclosing braces

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need to loop through all the matches in say the following string:

`<a href='/Product/Show/{ProductRowID}'>{ProductName}</a>`

I am looking to capture the values in the {} including them, so I want {ProductRowID} and {ProductName}

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim r As Regex = New Regex("{\w*}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim m As Match = r.Match("<a href='/Product/Show/{ProductRowID}'>{ProductName}</a>")
```

Is my RegEx pattern correct?  How do I loop through the matched values? I feel like this should be super easy but I have been stumped on this this morning!

Comment: [Beware of Zalgo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135078)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Pattern is missing a small detail:

```
\{\w*?\}
```

Curly braces must be escaped, and you want the non-greedy star, or your first (and only) match will be this: `"{ProductRowID}'>{ProductName}"`.

```
Dim r As Regex = New Regex("\{\w*?\}")
Dim input As String = "<a href='/Product/Show/{ProductRowID}'>{ProductName}</a>"
Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, r)
For Each m As Match In mc
  MsgBox.Show(m.ToString())
Next m
```

`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is not needed, because this particular regex is not case sensitive anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can just group your matches using a regex like the following:

```
<a href='/Product/Show/(.+)'\>(.+)</a>
```

In this way you have $1 and $2 matching the values you want to get.

You an also give your matches names so that they aren't anonymous/position oriented for retrieval:

```
<a href='/Product/Show/(?<rowid>.+)'\>(?<name>.+)</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your RegEx pattern to `\{\w*\}` then it will match as you expect.

You can test it with an [online .net RegEx tester](http://www.dotnetcoders.com/web/Learning/Regex/RegexTester.aspx).

Comment: Ok, here's another one:

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx